# How can one change the "Date Added" of a book in Adobe Digital Edition?

Tags: metadata, adobe-digital-editions

I recently installed Adobe Digital Edition (ADE) on my computer.

On ADE, each book has some associated metadata. The one I am interested in is the "Date Added" which is the date and time the book was loaded into ADE. It is  important for various reasons, and is in particular one of the data used to order the presentation of books.

For personnal reasons, related to the way I manage my (meta)data, I would like to be able to occasionally change that "Date Added" for a given book. (I want some books to be displayed together).

My question is :
How can I change the "Date Added" of a book in ADE?

What I tried:

I do know in what folder the book files are stored, and I did check that the "Date Added" corresponds precisely to the date of creation of the corresponding book file.  So I tried to change that date on the file.  I did succeed in changing the date of the file, but it had no effect on the "Date Added" displayed by ADE which remained the same.

I run ADE on Linux, but I guess answers based on other systems could be helpful too.